# Database Querying issue in Entity Framework. Getting null each time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

My problem is, that every time when I try querying the database with LinQ methods, I get either `Null` when using `SingleOrDefault()`, or an `InvalidOperationException` when using `Single()`.

Here's my code.

```
var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

var post = ApplicationDbContext.Posts
                .Include(c => c.Author)
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Author.Id == currentUser.Id);

if (post == null)
    return View(new CertainPost());
```

I'm suspicious if it ain't wrong that I've used the `.Include` method on author and in the same time I used the author value to query the DB. If that's the issue, how should I write this properly? Can I in some way use `SingleOrDefault()` method later in my code, when `Author` will be loaded? I've been doing it like this, but I find this way very messy

```
//Such a mess
var posts = ApplicationDbContext.Posts
                .Include(c => c.Author)
                .ToList();

foreach(var item in posts)
{
    if(item.Author.Id == currentUser.Id)
        var post = ApplicationDbContext.Posts.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.Id==item.Id)
}
```

So, what code should I write to compromise on usefulness and optimization?

Comment: Try if this works...`var post = ApplicationDbContext.Posts.Include(c => c.Author)
                .ToList().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Author.Id == currentUser.Id);`

Comment: Nah, still the same. I feel like i cant use `.Include(c => c.Author)` and immedeatly ask for it in `c => c.Author.Id == currentUser.Id` in the same expression. I guess it should load authors 1st, and then I should ask for author Id. But the issue is i don't know how to write it, because if I won't use SingleOrDefault, Single or ToList(), It returns IQueryable<> object, instead of Post object.

Comment: If you have a referenced entity `Author`, then you should also have an `AuthorId` property in your `Post` class - no? Just use that: `.SingleOrDefault(p => p.AuthorId == currentUser.Id);`

Comment: Nah, I aint got authorId class, I used object binding, So i've got property `public ApplicationUser Author {get;set}` instead of `public int AuthorId {get;set}`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your query. `Include` is unrelated to what you put as criteria because the query is translated to SQL. May be simply there are no posts for the user you are querying.

Comment: There is a post, because i've created it, and i see it in list (Differrent controller) also when i use messy lines of code it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that you have *multiple* posts for that author. The only meaningful logical difference between the non-working code and the working but "messy" code is that, in the working code, you're selecting by an item id.

The difference between `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` is only that when the first fails, it raises an exception, while the second will simply return null. With either, there's actually two scenarios that will make them fail:

1. There are no matching items
2. There are more than one matching items

Since you're sure that the first is not the situation (you've confirmed there is a post), then the second is the issue.

Long and short, you need to either provide some other differentiating detail to `SingleOrDefault` such that it can match one and only one post, or you need to just use something like `Where` and return all matching posts:

```
var post = ApplicationDbContext.Posts
    .Include(c => c.Author)
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Author.Id == currentUser.Id && c.Id == postId);
```

Or

```
var posts = ApplicationDbContext.Posts
    .Include(c => c.Author)
    .Where(c => c.Author.Id == currentUser.Id);
```

FWIW, you don't need to use `Include` for any relationships that are part of the query. In the case of `Author`, it has to be joined in order to figure out if its id equals the current user's id, so it will already be included.

Additionally, it's an unnecessary query to lookup the user when all your need is the id. You already *have* the id, since you used that to look the user up in the first place. You might have done that because passing `User.Identity.GetUserId()` directly to your query will raise an exception. However, that only occurs because Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate that method to something it can do in a SQL query. If you pass it just the value, you're fine:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var posts = ApplicationDbContext.Posts
    .Where(c => c.Author.Id == userId);
```

Comment: Actually, posts and authors are in 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: That may have been your intention, but I don't think that's actually the situation. If you post your entity classes, we might be able to spot a potential problem.

Comment: allthough i have only one post in database for Now. I'm not home Now so I can't show it